# jQuery vs Safari autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, safari

I use jQuery ui autocomplete plugin (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

On Safari I get two autocomplete list:

- one from jQuery (expected, the one bellow with 1 item)
- one from the browser (unwanted, the one on top with 4 items)

[image: screenshot]

I've tried to use `<input type="text" autocomplete="off">` but the Safari autocomplete still appears.

What should I do to make it go away?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly all of the major browsers stopped honoring the autocomplete="off" attribute.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)  You could pottentially have some luck setting the autocomplete setting to an invalid value, but this solution will likely be hit or miss depending on the browser version.

> In some cases, the browser will keep suggesting autocompletion values even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. This unexpected behavior can be quite puzzling for developers. The trick to really forcing the no-autocompletion is to assign a random string to the attribute, for example:

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

Another workaround that some users appear to have success with is the following.  Post a comment and let me know if this works for you.

// Override Safari, Chrome and IE11 decision to ignore autocomplete: off
// on form you wish to skip autocomplete, change all password fields to type=private
// requires jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type="private"]').focus(function(e){
    $(this).prop('type', 'password');
  });
  $('input[type="private"]').parents('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type="password"]').hide().prop('type', 'private');
  });
});
```